# Is the term "expendable capital" superfluous?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I want to use the term...

> "expendable capital"

...to describe...

> "a company's available budget for a particular thing"

Am I using the the word "capital" innaccurately and is all capital not expendable therefore rendering my use of the word "expendable", superfluous?

Alternative recommendations are welcome.

Comment: I would use "available budget".  I can't say that "expendable capital" is necessarily wrong, but it's particularly idiomatic.

Comment: And some capital may not be free to be spent, because it must be held as a security against certain debts or other reasons.

Comment: Can anyone educate me as to why my question may have been down-voted to assist me in avoiding a repeat of the mistake in future questions?

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you for your provided clarification.

Comment: Oops -- should have said "..  it's *not* particularly idiomatic."

Comment: @HotLicks Acknowledged.

Answer (score 1):

**non-expendable capital**

[Example](http://www.vacareers.va.gov/vacareers/careers/physicians/job-detail.asp?job=e14e1e-inventory-management-specialist-tcf-student-big-spring-tx)

> The incumbent will gain experience and in-depth knowledge of logistics
> operations, including acquisition and purchasing of expendable
> materials/supplies and **non-expendable capital assets** and equipment
> and inventory management. An in-depth understanding of the
> regulations, policies, directives, processes and standard operating
> procedures and management thereof will be attained.
>
> From US department of Veterans' Affairs (Part of a job-description)

Search online for "non expendable capital" to find other examples.

Comment: Is your point that, by merit of the term "non-expendable capital" existing, "expendable capital" is equally acceptable?

Comment: Chasly from UK--government job descriptions and pamphlets are not noted for clarity of expression. These tracts are rife with bureaucratese and redundancies. e.g,, a  'guide' becomes a 'Guide to Information' in government-speak.